# Clipping the center of an image in CSS

Tags: css, mask, clip-path

I'm trying to put a translucent overlay in front a fullscreen video and as the target for taking a photo.

The part I'm trying to clip out is shown in white in this image: https://ibb.co/cK6xb8

clip-path is capable is clipping the outside of an image but how can you clip the inside?

Comment: Maybe this helps. https://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/

Comment: ?? you want the image to show only on the white part or only on the outside ?  else mix-blend-mode could be an alternative inside or outside works , you need a mask demo using text for a mask https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rWrvKP (it is about the colors used )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with polygons in `clip-path`. Check out [Clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) and choose the frame option for an example.

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 25% 75%, 25% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 25% 75%, 25% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
```

[image]